# Issue with implementing synchronous operation in activity diagram

Tags: activity-diagram

I want to draw activity diagram to test a specific phone. I have tried to start with synchronous operation on choosing 3 random phone . can you please check if I have done them correctly , just started learning this process and couldn't figure out if I have to use synchronous or loop for choosing 3 random phone as well

1. To that I am choosing  3 same type phone randomly for the test.
2. Initially I check for packaging damage - if it had damage then return to production manager
3. If no package damage - then open box and check for physical damage - if damage found then return to production manger
4. if no physical damage then test for functionality damage - if no damage then [image]consider the product as Test passed.

Answer (score 0):

The first horizontal bar is a fork node, meaning that the control flow is split into three concurrent threads. So A1, A2, and A3 are three actions that are executed in parallel. The second horizontal bar is a join node, meaning that once that all of these actions have been finished, the control flow will continue (with the first decision).

I think that this is *not* what you want to show: The first action "Randomly take 3 samples" already gives you three samples and you would process each one of them in the same way, so you should rather have a loop with three iterations around the part with the decisions.

In general, try distinguish between actions, objects and states - A1, A2, A3 seem to be objects and not actions, and "Test passed" is the resulting state and not an action either.

The part with the three decisions itself is fine (except that personally I like to draw the control flow either from top to bottom or from left to right, but not back - but this is a matter of taste).

[Here is an introduction to activity diagrams](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-activity-diagram/) with some good examples.